# How to limit query to return only weekday values

Tags: sql, oracle, weekday

I have the below query, which is pulling 2 dates: "trade date" and "contract expiration". I would like to only see the previous *business* days trades and corresponding contract expirations. I was hoping to be able to somehow pull this out in the where clause, but the query is bounced back when I try to call `prev_weekday`. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    p.tradedate as current_date,
    case when to_char(p.tradedate, 'D') in (1,6,7)
         then next_day(ip.tradedate, 'Monday')
         else p.tradedate + 1 end 
                             as next_weekday,
    case when to_char(p.tradedate, 'D') in (1,2,7)
         then next_day(ip.tradedate-7, 'Friday')
         else p.tradedate - 1 end
                             as prev_weekday,
    p.tradedate,
    p.contractexpiration
FROM db.cmd h
JOIN db.stl p ON p.id = h.p_id
WHERE p.tradedate BETWEEN trunc(sysdate,'YEAR')
                      AND add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR'),12) - 1/24/60/60/
```

Comment: It's a terrible idea to write hard-coded business day logic that assumes that weekdays are business days and weekends are not. The only safe thing to do is to create a table with a list of all dates for the foreseeable future, with a flag or value indicating whether the day is a business day or not. Join to the table to perform logic that involves business days.

Comment: What does "the query is bounced back when I try to call prev_weekday." mean? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I've found a business logic table. But still unable to pull in just the previous business day.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you want; are you trying to get records where the adjusted next_weekday or prev_weekday is the last business day (from your logic table) before today? Does the prev/next need to work from that table too? Might be helpful to edit the question and explain the rules, show the table structures, and give some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

If you try it with a trick, add few new fields "trade_weekday" and "expiration_weekday" and when you add a new record add the day of those date too. After, you only need restrict a weekdays or discards the weekends. I think if this query is a very important in your application, this solution will be a good way to improve this query.